# Dynamic tag manager rule for video

Tags: html, video-tracking

I want to set up a rule using Dynamic Tag manager to monitor activity on some video on my website. I use HTML file to play videos as popup. Something like below.

```
<iframe width="620" height="349" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/896dfsd996sdf?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have already setup a rule in DTM using Event - "%complete" and "time complete" but it's not working.

[image: This image show my rule in Dynamic Tag manger]

Below is my html coding which calls a HTML file from an image click event

```
<a id="home-page-andy-graves-video-play" href="/portals/37/Video/yt-exec-Andy-Graves.html" class="vidpopup cboxElement hide-for-small-only">
<img alt="Home page carousal banner" src="/portals/37/Images/Home/c11-1.jpg">
```

Any idea what is missing? May be something wrong the HTML file?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If possible, you should share a [mcve] so we can see the actual problem, your code, and any error messages that could be happening.

Comment: My question is edited with more details. Thank you for the reply. :)